# POM error on Ubuntu

Tags: maven

I am new to Maven. I am trying to install Apache Zeppelin for Spark on Ubuntu which is installed on a VM. For that I need to have JAVA and MAVEN installed on the machine. I ran the below statement

```
sudo apt-get install maven
```

It ran successfully. I checked the version (Successful)

```
hduser@HDPMaster:/usr$ mvn -version

Apache Maven 3.0.5
Maven home: /usr/share/maven
Java version: 1.7.0_91, vendor: Oracle Corporation
Java home: /usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-amd64/jre
Default locale: en_US, platform encoding: UTF-8
OS name: "linux", version: "3.19.0-43-generic", arch: "amd64", family:    "unix"
```

This below command gave me an error.

```
mvn install -DskipTests

    [INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 0.216s
[INFO] Finished at: Tue Jan 12 09:35:15 PST 2016
[INFO] Final Memory: 6M/55M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] The goal you specified requires a project to execute but there is no POM in this directory (/usr). Please verify you invoked Maven from the correct directory. -> [Help 1]
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MissingProjectException
```

Not sure what is this POM file and where is it located.

Any inputs will be appreciated

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to run `mvn install` from zeppelin folder. As you can see here: https://github.com/apache/incubator-zeppelin, pom.xml IS in the project root. So, just install all needed dependencies, `cd incubator-zeppelin`, and `mvn install` from there.

Comment: Thanks @Fantast..the Zeppelin root folder had a POM.XML file and the MVN install executed for me. Now I am facing other challenges which I may post as a different thread (if unresolved ). Thanks for the help !

Answer (score 0):

POM stands for Project Object Model. So in any Maven project you have to create a pom.xml file which contains all the details about the what to do when you run `mvn install`. Which includes:

- Project name, description, build output (jar/war file)
- Project's dependency on other local maven projects/ projects residing at a remote repository. By default it is the maven repository.
- And various other information.

When you run `mvn install`, maven expects a pom.xml file. Or in other words, you always got to run the command from project root location.